# Create DataFrame with Categorical Data Above or Below Average

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, assign

i have a dataframe with monthly data and monthly averages in columns that Im showing below for each month and each variable that is separated by the column 'plant_name'. I need to assign a '1' if the row or monthly data value is above zero and a '0' if the data is below the average. My data looks like this in df1:

```
    plant_name  year    month   windspeed   temperature air_density richardson_nbr  air_pressure    relative_humidity   wind_direction_deg  windspeed_avg   temperature_avg air_density_avg richardson_nbr_avg  air_pressure_avg    relative_humidity_avg   wind_direction_deg_avg
0   ALPHA   1990    1   8.5   4.7   1.2   0.7   961.0   67.4    252.0   5.6 2.8 1.2 2.9 965.1   72.4    198.4
1   ALPHA   1991    1   5.5   1.8   1.2   9.2   968.1   66.4    232.0   5.6 2.8 1.2 2.9 965.1   72.4    198.4
2   ALPHA   1992    1   4.9   4.2   1.2   3.2   964.3   73.8    240.0   5.6 2.8 1.2 2.9 965.1   72.4    198.4
3   ALPHA   1993    1   4.0  -2.8   1.2   3.5   963.4   76.1    74.0    5.6 2.8 1.2 2.9 965.1   72.4    198.4
4   STAR    2019    12  4.8   3.0   1.2   4.1   948.7   77.9    202.0   6.3 1.3 1.2 5.0 950.1   75.9    143.2
5   STAR    2020    12  5.9   2.9   1.2   0.6   954.0   78.4    79.0    6.3 1.3 1.2 5.0 950.1   75.9    143.2
6   STAR    2021    12  6.9   1.8   1.2   4.7   943.3   74.2    230.0   6.3 1.3 1.2 5.0 950.1   75.9    143.2
7   STAR    2022    12  6.1  -0.5   1.2   0.5   948.3   74.3    77.0    6.3 1.3 1.2 5.0 950.1   75.9    143.2
```

My result in a new dataframe (df2) needs to look like this:

```
    plant_name  year    month   windspeed   temperature air_density richardson_nbr  air_pressure    relative_humidity   wind_direction_deg
0   ALPHA   1990    9   1   1   0   0   0   0   252
1   ALPHA   1991    9   0   0   1   1   1   0   232
2   ALPHA   1992    9   0   1   0   1   0   1   240
3   ALPHA   1993    9   0   0   1   1   0   1   74
4   STAR    2019    12  0   1   0   0   0   1   202
5   STAR    2020    12  0   1   0   0   1   1   79
6   STAR    2021    12  1   1   0   0   0   0   230
7   STAR    2022    12  0   0   1   0   0   0   77
```

The wind_direction column is copied with no categorical value associated with it. thank you for your help and ideas.